# Failed to load Glass factory class - OpenJDK OpenJFX on Windows

Tags: java, javafx, openjfx

I'm trying to run a JavaFX app on Windows. It runs fine on Ubuntu. But on Windows I'm getting the error "Failed to load Glass factory class". A Class Not Found Exception.

[image: Failed to load Glass factory class]

edit...

It seems JavaFX jars are not cross platform. Compiling on Linux doesn't create a jar that runs on Windows. Compiling on Windows and including the JavaFX jars in the compile creates a jar that runs even without JavaFX installed.

Comment: Did you miss any files? It seems that some JavaFX classes are available but others aren't

Comment: When I copy the jfx files to the jdk... alot of file names are the same and I have not been overwriting any files. Do you think maybe overwrites? I'll give it a go.

Comment: Overwriting the files makes no difference. Same error.

Comment: no screenshots of text please - they are unreadable. it's text which can be ... c&p'ed ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using [Azul's Zulu OpenJDK](https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/) builds, which bundle OpenJFX, even for JDK 11.

[image]

Comment: This has worked. It wasn't quite the answer I had hoped for. I'd like to know what I did wrong when adding the OpenJFX files to the OpenJDK. But you've got me out of trouble for the meantime. Upvoted... it might be the accepted answer if nothing better turns up. Thanks a bunch.